# Render cutting off

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've re-started (3.0) and I've never had this problem before, the render will not show the full 1920x1080 image that I'm expecting to see. There appears to be small orange "crop" marks at the corner of this image but its cutting it off?

[image]

Comment: Ssounds as if you've inadvertantly selected a render region with CTRL-B. Try CTRL-ALT-B and see if you see the full image.

Comment: Look at the status bar and you can see it's doing tiled rendering just with two very large tiles.  Once that segment of your image finishes it will move on to the other.

Comment: provide blend file so we can check it out instead of guessing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we can see in the informations above your render, it is mentioned that you are rendering tiles.

[Tile rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html#tiles) is most likely not preferable to use since v3.0. So unless you have a specific setup that you know requires it, I suggest you turn it off.

`Properties` Editor > `Render` tab > `Performance` panel > `Memory` subpanel > uncheck `Use Tiling`:

[image: use tiling]

Comment: L0Lock......awesome! Thank you so much. I was going insane trying to figure this out and I have no idea how that checkbox got selected/ticked. Cheers!

Comment: AFAIK it is checked by default, but the default tile size is 2048, which is big enough to fill a 1920x1080 render at once. If you have an addon that impacts that or opened a .blend from a previous Blender version, that could be why.

Comment: This file was opened from 2.9 and I wanted to render it (for Client) using 3.0 so perhaps that helps to explain as you suggest.

Comment: Absolutely! Cycles got a big rewrite for v3.0, so previous versions of Blender had a very different way of handling render and particularly the tiles system is very different. (In a way, Blender doesn't use one render device per tile anymore, so the previous principle of "divide and conquer" we used to have isn't valid as of 3.0. But Any scene created with an older version still used tiles settings that are made around that old principle. So be aware of that.