# Final render gets cropped whenever i change the resolution to something above 1920x1080

Tags: cycles-render-engine, resolution, output

[image: cropped render]

I've been trying to resize the render resolution adjusting the format, but when i hit render, the final image gets a large transparent area that is not rendered. As i increase the resolution size, it gets worse.
Any ideas on what i am getting wrong an how to solve this?

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: Do you have a Render Region set? Ctrl+B lets you define a region, Ctrl+Alt+B removes it. Try the 2nd shortcut and render again.

Comment: @oaaya Render Region is disabled (you can see it in the screenshot under _Format_ settings). The keywords here are "something above 1920×1080" - it's a tiling problem, see my answer.

Comment: Simple as that. My bad, I missed the status bar info.

Comment: It's actually a similar problem like this question [Render cutting off](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250122/) only that there it seems to be an older file opened in a newer version that kept a smaller tile size. Unfortunately the question is closed for lack of clarity, although all necessary information is given in the screenshot.

Answer (score 9):

Your render hasn't finished yet as you can see in the screenshot. It says *"Rendered 0/2 Tiles"* so not even the one you can see is finished.

With the implementation of *Cycles X* the tile size is not gone completely, it is hidden under *Render Properties* > *Performance* > *Memory*. There you have the option *Use Tiling*, and the default *Tile Size* is 2048.

This tile size works for the standard 1920 × 1080 render size since no dimension is larger than 2048. But if you try to render images that exceed this pixel size in any dimension, the render gets tiled.

To be clear: you can, but don't really need to change anything, you can simply wait until Blender has finished rendering.

[image: tiling]